# What should I know when applying for my first job?

Tags: interviewing, resume, salary, first-job

I am entering the workplace for the first time. What do I need to know before getting started?

> <sup>This post is a [community wiki](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) meant to help answer questions that would otherwise be considered 'too broad' by referencing other content on the site. If you think other posts are high-quality and relevant, please add them to [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/20324/98). Please see [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2416/7945) for more details.</sup>

Answer (score 72, accepted):

### Cover letter

Resumes are how you show what you know, where you learnt it. A [cover-letter](/questions/tagged/cover-letter) is how you show why you want the job, and why you would be a good candidate:

- [Is a cover letter really necessary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/is-a-cover-letter-really-necessary)
- [Should I include a cover letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60611/should-i-include-a-cover-letter)
- [Generic cover letter, or none at all?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/generic-cover-letter-or-none-at-all)

### Resume

First polish up your [resume](/questions/tagged/resume). Here is some helpful advice on how to do that:

- [Why is a one to two page résumé recommended?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/844)
- [Should I include a career objective on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1)
- [My GPA wasn't the best, how can I make it not look as bad?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/227/7945)
- [As a student, how should programming language familiarity be described on a CV/Resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/)
- [How Should I Indicate Language Proficiency on my Resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/how-should-i-indicate-language-proficiency-on-my-resume)

### Interviewing

Once you have the resume handled, brush up on your [interviewing](/questions/tagged/interviewing) skills:

- [What should I wear to an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/)
- [How should I respond to interview questions when I don't know the answer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18814)
- [In an interview, is it required to have question(s) for the interviewer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3265)
- [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/)

### Negotiating Salary

After nailing the interviews, it's time to think about [salary](/questions/tagged/salary):

- [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)
- [How can I use my masters degree to get a higher salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10343/how-can-i-use-my-masters-degree-to-get-a-higher-salary)
- [Should I list salary expectations on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12239/)

> <sup>This post is a [community wiki](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) meant to help answer questions that would otherwise be considered 'too broad' by referencing other content on the site. If you think other posts are high-quality and relevant, please add them to this post. Please see [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2416/7945) for more details.</sup>

Comment: A feedback from someone who is not "at home" at [workplace.se]: The question [What should I wear to an interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/) does not really cover the general case when you are not told what to wear to an interview. In many companies (think IT and applied engineering), you're likely not expected to wear a tie for an interview -- certianly the question does not cover this situataion, but from its title, it looks like it's a very general question.