# Should I include an "About Me" section in my CV? Or put it in the cover letter?

Tags: resume

I have a 2-sentence about me section which basically says I have a desire for learning and looking into the future.

Should I include it in the CV or Cover Letter?

Comment: Put it in the cover letter and adapt it for each reciipient.

Comment: Second question removed, see the Cover Letter section in [What should I know when applying for my first job?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/what-should-i-know-when-applying-for-my-first-job?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I won't vote to close since the pros/cons of an "about me" section *can* be answered but you should know that what you intend to put there is completely meaningless and will have a net negative effect on your resume.

Comment: "I have a desire for learning and looking into the future." - I don't see any value to adding that to either document.

Comment: You're suggesting words. If you don't have something to back those words, you look like you don't know yourself and your goals well. If you do have something, you don't need those words.

Answer (score 3):

**I would not put a general statement "I have a desire for learning and looking into the future" anywhere.**

I think this is generic "I'm a good employee" stuff which doesn't really say something specific about you, and doesn't really help your case, since everyone would express such sentiments to a potential employer.

***Do* put some more specific information about you in the cover letter.**  But it should be more distinctive than this, as well as targeted to the position.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't include a statement like that in either section.  It means nothing and will likely be ignored.  In both the cover letter and CV, include things that are tangible and valuable, anything else is just window dressing.

As a resume reviewer, I want to see things that give me a demonstrable reason to believe you will be successful.  Instead of saying "I have a desire for learning and looking into the future", point to things in your CV which demonstrate that you have taken actions to learn new things and work with new technologies.  I will determine from those items that you really do want to learn and look to the future.

You can say all the nice things you want, but remember the old saying "Actions speak louder than words."

Answer (score 2):

A CV is for general information, whereas a cover letter is directed towards a specific target.

Since your 'About me' section sounds very general, I would put it in the CV.

A cover letter should elaborate on the parts of the CV the target would care about.